# Where can I edit Admin Panel Page file

Tags: wp-admin, pages, contextual-help

I need to edit the "Help" section of the "Page" page in the Admin panel. Since wordpress doesn't allow multiple line breaks I need to make sure the user knows that if they add the "
" tag in the HTML section they will achieve the line break so I figure what better place to add this than the help section. I can't seem to find the Page file though. Directory Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the custom help by adding a hook to the page load e.g. `page-new.php` would become `load-page-new.php`

```
function custom_help_page() {
  add_filter('contextual_help','custom_page_help');
}

function custom_page_help($help) {
  $custom =  "<h5>Custom Help</h5>
              <p>Custom help content</p>";
  return $custom.$help; 
}

add_action('load-page-new.php','custom_help_page'); //New page
add_action('load-page.php','custom_help_page'); //Page, edits, updates etc.
```

If you don't want the default help to still display, simply remove `echo $help;`

Edited to return rather echo the values.

Comment: Well I still want the help information that is there, I just want to add to the test. Where is help variable for "Pages" located?

Comment: They all use the default $help variable. If you echo it then it should still display.

Comment: You shouldn't echo with a filter, you should append or prepend the information you want to add and return it.

Comment: @helenhousandi I have edited my answer, does that look the correct way?

Comment: Yes, that's much more correct :) I'd also use a less-generic function name for namespacing, usually just myprefix_ or something.