# Editing Help Section

Tags: widgets, admin, pages, links, contextual-help

I was trying to find the contextual help section for all the admin pages so I could add some additional text. The main pages I need to hit are the "Pages" page and the "Widgets" page but I'm not sure where to find the files for these. Anybody know file names where I can find the contextual help?

Comment: why did you ask the same question again? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28417/where-can-i-edit-admin-panel-page-file

Comment: because I didn't exactly find my answer. Luckily the answer below was extremely helpful.

Comment: you make the site less useful to others by littering it with unanswered questions. you should edit your questions with additional info, reasons why answers are not working, etc., if you're not getting answers that work for you.

Comment: Wow, I even commented on the other one and didn't notice that it was the same asker :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT edit core files! You can add to or override the default text by using a filter. Try taking a look at http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/02/adding-contextual-help-to-plugin-and-theme-admin-pages